# Adding ca-certificates to a Tomcat Docker container run with a designated user

Tags: docker, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, dockerfile

I have a Docker volume mounted directly to the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates -folder.

```
certificate-folder:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates:ro
```

I'm using Tomcat for this setup, but a similar issue could be encountered with other frameworks as well. Base of the Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM       tomcat:8.5-jre8
# other Dockerfile configuration
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

With start.sh containing key lines

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
update-ca-certificates 
# other startup related tasks
catalina.sh run
```

Issue with this setup is that it works as long as I'm running the container as root user. However, if I try to change to a designated user at the end of the Dockerfile with something like this

```
ENV TOMCAT_USER="tomcat" \
    TOMCAT_UID="8080" \
    TOMCAT_GROUP="tomcat" \
    TOMCAT_GID="8080"
RUN groupadd -r --gid $TOMCAT_GID $TOMCAT_GROUP && \
    useradd -r --uid $TOMCAT_UID --gid $TOMCAT_GID $TOMCAT_USER
RUN chown -R $TOMCAT_USER:$TOMCAT_GROUP /usr/local/tomcat
USER $TOMCAT_USER
```

So:

- Because the shell script is being run as $TOMCAT_USER, it can't run "update-ca-certificates" to install the certificates.
- Because certificates aren't added inside Dockerfile, update-ca-certificates can't be run inside Dockerfile.

Because of this I'm eventually getting SSL issues like this

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So what would be the correct way to approach this kind of issue if I still wish to run the container as a designated $TOMCAT_USER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `update-ca-certificates` needs root permissions to update the certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs`, I only see three possible approaches (and one working solution − the third one below):

1. Remove `update-ca-certificates` from your entrypoint and add a `RUN update-ca-certificates` command before the line `USER $TOMCAT_USER`. (However, you are using a volume which won't be available at build time, so this couldn't work…)
2. Give `sudo` permissions (with no password) to your `$TOMCAT_USER`, and replace `update-ca-certificates` with `sudo update-ca-certificates`. (However, this solution may be unsatisfactory from a security perspective…)
3. Remove `USER $TOMCAT_USER` from your Dockerfile; keep `CMD ["/start.sh"]`, or `ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]` if you prefer; and rely on the [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) tool, whose main use case precisely consists in downgrading from *root* to a non-privileged user, while enjoying better behavior than *sudo* w.r.t. TTY and signal forwarding.

   You'll just need to install `gosu` by doing for example:

   ```
   RUN apt-get update -y -q && \
     DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
     apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends gosu
   ```

   (as `tomcat:8.5-jre8` is based on Debian) and use it by writing:

   > start.sh

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   update-ca-certificates 
   # other startup related tasks
   exec gosu $TOMCAT_UID:$TOMCAT_GID catalina.sh run
   ```

Comment: @mpartan note that one shouldn't forget prepending "exec" before "gosu", as recalled in this comment: https://github.com/tianon/gosu/issues/37#issuecomment-308186951 (see also https://github.com/tianon/gosu#warning)